# Unable to Complete iOS In App Purchase for Newly Created Auto Renewing Subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing iOS In App Purchasing for Auto Renewing subscriptions within my app. I HAVE NOT YET SUBMITTED THE APP FOR REVIEW. I initially created two auto renewing purchases within the app store and was able to test them fine. Everything was working correctly. Then I found out I needed to change the pricing.

The only way to change the pricing was to delete the old auto renewing purchases and create new ones. Now when I try to purchase one of these with a sandbox user it fails. The purchase meta data shows up correctly within my app (i.e. Price, Title, Description, Id). But when I go through the purchasing process it fails.

Within App Store Connect I see this message from within the Features tab.

> Your first in-app purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Create your in-app purchase, then select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section under App Store and click Submit. Learn More
>
> Once your binary has been uploaded and your first in-app purchase has been submitted for review, additional in-app purchases can be submitted using the table below.

I'm wondering if because I deleted the initial purchases that I created I must now actually submit an app to have the purchases be accessible for testing. This seems like a huge flaw in the system because now I'm just kind of hoping and praying it works or they get approved otherwise I'll have no way to even test it to make sure it is working.

Comment: Is the new purchase in the "Ready To Submit" state?

Comment: Also, this may be related to a widespread issue in Sandbox right now: https://twitter.com/RevenueCat/status/1106235357413036032

Comment: Yep. It’s in a ready to submit state.

Comment: Sounds like it’s the issue posted by revenue cat. Would be nice if Apple gave a heads up of any kind. Grab, Ive been trying to figure this out since yesterday.